# How to have different synchronized blocks for different members of an Object in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to understand synchronized block in java.

In C/C++, we have mutex to protect a critical section. So, if an object has two resources say i and j, and if there are two interfaces SetI and SetJ which modify i and j respectively, i would declare two mutexes, each of which protect i and j, simple!

Now i am trying to simulate the same thing in java.

Consider a thread which enters synchronized(obj) and wants to modify its member i.

Then can i not have another thread enter a different synchronized block but of the same object, which needs to modify other member of obj called j?

I have attached a sample code which is trying to do the above task, but only one thread gets the chance and the other thread which wants to modify other variable never gets the chance.

If the resources which are to be protected were objects i would have taken the synchronized on the members themselves, i and j. But since these are primitive data types, i can't use them in synchronized(i tried, but got compilation error). So, i am forced to synchronize on "this".

The question is not why only one thread is getting the chance to execute which i understand. Rather, How do i achieve my requirement which is "two threads modifying two different resources of an object shouldn't block on each other".

```
class object
{
    private boolean i;
    private boolean j;

    public void flipi(String arg)
    {
        synchronized(this)
        {
            while(true)
            {
                i = !i;
                System.out.println("flipi "+ "thread: " + arg + " value of i: " + i);
                try
                {
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    System.out.println(e);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void flipj(String arg)
    {
        synchronized(this)
        {
            while(true)
            {
                j = !j;
                System.out.println("flipj "+ "thread: " + arg + " value of j: " + j );
                try
                {
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    System.out.println(e);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

class test extends Thread
{
    object obj;

    test(object obj)
    {
        this.obj = obj;
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        String threadname = Thread.currentThread().getName();

        if(threadname.equals("test1"))
        {
            obj.flipi(Thread.currentThread().getName());
        }
        else if(threadname.equals("test2"))
        {
            obj.flipj(Thread.currentThread().getName());
        }
    }
}

public class testsynchronized
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        object obj = new object();

        test t1 = new test(obj);
        test t2 = new test(obj);

        t1.setName("test1");
        t2.setName("test2");

        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }
}
```

output:

```
$ java testsynchronized
flipj thread: test2 value of j: true
flipj thread: test2 value of j: false
flipj thread: test2 value of j: true
flipj thread: test2 value of j: false
flipj thread: test2 value of j: true
flipj thread: test2 value of j: false
flipj thread: test2 value of j: true
flipj thread: test2 value of j: false
flipj thread: test2 value of j: true
flipj thread: test2 value of j: false
flipj thread: test2 value of j: true
flipj thread: test2 value of j: false
flipj thread: test2 value of j: true
flipj thread: test2 value of j: false
flipj thread: test2 value of j: true
flipj thread: test2 value of j: false
flipj thread: test2 value of j: true
flipj thread: test2 value of j: false
flipj thread: test2 value of j: true
flipj thread: test2 value of j: false
flipj thread: test2 value of j: true
flipj thread: test2 value of j: false
flipj thread: test2 value of j: true
flipj thread: test2 value of j: false
flipj thread: test2 value of j: true
flipj thread: test2 value of j: false
flipj thread: test2 value of j: true
flipj thread: test2 value of j: false
flipj thread: test2 value of j: true
flipj thread: test2 value of j: false
flipj thread: test2 value of j: true
flipj thread: test2 value of j: false
flipj thread: test2 value of j: true
flipj thread: test2 value of j: false
flipj thread: test2 value of j: true
flipj thread: test2 value of j: false
flipj thread: test2 value of j: true
flipj thread: test2 value of j: false
flipj thread: test2 value of j: true
flipj thread: test2 value of j: false
flipj thread: test2 value of j: true
```

Comment: You have an infinite loop inside your synchronized block. Once one thread enters it, it never leaves, so no other thread can enter the synchronized block.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49496459/how-to-selectively-protect-an-object-resources-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an infinite loop inside your synchronized blocks, and they are both synchronizing on the same thing (`this`). Once one thread enters it, it never leaves, so no other thread can enter the synchronized block.

To allow different threads to update different variables without interfering with one another, synchronize the updates of those variables on different things:

```
private final Object iGuard = new Object();
private final Object jGuard = new Object();
```

Then:

```
synchronized (iGuard) { i = !i; }
```

And

```
synchronized (jGuard) { j = !j; }
```

---

Incidentally, switching behaviour on thread name is basically never the right thing to do. Just create your threads like so:

```
Thread t1 = new Thread(a -> a.flipi("Thread 1"));
Thread t2 = new Thread(a -> a.flipj("Thread 2"));

t1.start();
t2.start();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer ... Is this the standard approach followed or is it some kind of a hack? And also is it possible to take synchronized on multiple lock objects?

Comment: This is the standard approach. You can nest synchronized blocks, e.g. `sychronized (a) { synchronized (b) { .. } }`.

Comment: (But be careful not to create a deadlock when synchronizing on multiple objects... look it up)

Answer (score 1):

instead of synchronising on 'this' you can create a 2 different lock objects and sync on them:

```
class object
{
    private boolean i;
    private boolean j;
    Object lock1 = new Object();
    Object lock2 = new Object();

    public void flipi(String arg)
    {
        synchronized(lock1)
        {
            while(true)
            {
                i = !i;
                System.out.println("flipi "+ "thread: " + arg + " value of i: " + i);
                try
                {
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    System.out.println(e);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void flipj(String arg)
    {
        synchronized(lock2)
        {
            while(true)
            {
                j = !j;
                System.out.println("flipj "+ "thread: " + arg + " value of j: " + j );
                try
                {
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    System.out.println(e);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

class test extends Thread
{
    object obj;

    test(object obj)
    {
        this.obj = obj;
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        String threadname = Thread.currentThread().getName();

        if(threadname.equals("test1"))
        {
            obj.flipi(Thread.currentThread().getName());
        }
        else if(threadname.equals("test2"))
        {
            obj.flipj(Thread.currentThread().getName());
        }
    }
}

public class testsynchronized
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        object obj = new object();

        test t1 = new test(obj);
        test t2 = new test(obj);

        t1.setName("test1");
        t2.setName("test2");

        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can see,

```
while(true)
```

is running for your run() method that calls `flipi("threadName")`
Which means it never calls

```
 else if(threadname.equals("test2"))
```

and only first     `flipi` method runs in loop

To understand the same, try something else other than going into infinite loop